# Refactoring jQuery for react component

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, components

I am moving away from using jQuery to do some quick hides, shows and css changes because I am using components in react that need to be re-rendered and thus are not triggering the jQuery actions that need a page refresh. I think my issue is that I need to set the state in each component but I am a bit confused as to how. Here is an example of the jquery for this particular view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $(".schedule-times").hide();
           $(".final-check").hide();

           $(".available-time").on('click', function () {
              $(".schedule-times").toggle();
            });

            $(".schedule-button").on('click', function () {
              $('.finalize-timeline').css("background", "#4CAF50");
              $(".final-check").show();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is an example of a component I have written:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../../App.css';

import Calendar from '../Calendar';

import { Link } from 'react-router';

class Schedule_3 extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wow fadeIn"> 
        <div className="container"> 
            <div className="timeline">
                <div className="col-md-12 offset-md-2">
                    <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-2 timeline-box">
                                <div className="timeline-badge active-timeline">
                                <i className="fa fa-check wow bounceInDown"></i>
                                </div>
                                <span>How do you want to schedule?</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2 timeline-box">
                                <div className="timeline-badge active-timeline">
                                <i className="fa fa-check wow bounceInDown"></i>
                                </div>
                                <span>Pick your lesson type</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2 timeline-box">
                                <div className="timeline-badge active-timeline">
                                </div>
                                <span>Find a time</span>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-2 timeline-box">
                                <div className="timeline-badge" id="no_border">
                                </div>
                                <span>Finalize</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
                        <Calendar />
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div><br />
              <div className="row schedule-times">
                <div className="col-md-12 offset-md-2">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                            <i className="fa fa-clock"></i>&nbsp;
                            10:30AM
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                            <Link to="Schedule_4">
                                <button className="btn btn-primary">
                                Book Now
                                </button>
                            </Link>
                        </div>
                    </div><br />
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                            <i className="fa fa-clock"></i>&nbsp;
                            11:00AM
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary">
                            Book Now
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div><br />
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-4 offset-md-1">
                            <i className="fa fa-clock"></i>&nbsp;
                            11:30AM
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-1">
                            <button className="btn btn-primary">
                            Book Now
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Schedule_3;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code I would suggest the first thing you need to do is split it into smaller, more manageable and more readable components that are responsible for 1 thing.

As you have posted a big example I cannot show you how to do it for every case you have, but I can give you a simple example that can be adapted for your use cases.

```
class ToggleContent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = { hidden: true };

    this.toggleContent = this.toggleContent.bind(this);
  }

  toggleContent() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      hidden: !prevState.hidden
    }));
  }

  render() {
    const { hidden } = this.state;
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.toggleContent }>Toggle</button>
        <div>
          { !hidden && children }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

You can use this component like this `<ToggleContent>Hello World</ToggleContent>` and it will toggle visibility of `Hello World` on the button press. You can put anything inside of this, including other components, it doesn't have to just be text.

[You can see an example of it running here.](https://codesandbox.io/s/m9jny971q8)

You can see the state of whether the `children` are hidden or not is held in the component `this.state = { hidden: true };`.

The children are then rendered if it is not hidden, if `!hidden === true`. We can see that inline here `{ !hidden && children }`.

The `toggleContent` method is then using the previous state to switch back and forth between hidden and showing.

```
toggleContent() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      hidden: !prevState.hidden
    }));
  }
```

Comment: For some reason I can't seem to get that to work as a component within my own app to work backwards from. I appreciate the help tho.